# How to get the address which verify() returns from test script?

Tags: ethers.js, testing, unittesting

my `verify()` looks like this:

```
function verify(
        address _customer,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value,
        bytes32 _key,
        bytes memory _signature
    ) public alreadySubmitted returns(address){
        require(submitted[_customer]);
        _value = _value * 1 ether;
        bytes32 signature = getSignature(_to, _value, _key);
        address recovered = recoverSigner(signature, _signature);
        if (recovered == _customer) {
            verified[msg.sender] = true;
            emit Verified(msg.sender, "is now verified. Congrats!!");
        } 

        return recovered;
    }
```

If we call it from test script it should return an address, right?
But in my case it is returning the whole signature, this is the script:

```js
it("Provided signer address as input is equal to the caller address", async function () {
            const { multisig, signer, acc2, acc3, acc4, acc5 } =
                await loadFixture(deployMultisigFixture)
            const to = acc4.address
            const from = acc5.address
            const key =
                "0xdf57089febbacf7ba0bc227dafbffa9fc08a93fdc68e1e42411a14efcf23656f"
            const value = ethers.utils.parseEther("1")
            let signature = await multisig.getSignature(to, value, key)
            let _signature = ethers.utils.joinSignature(signature)
            await multisig.connect(acc5).submit(to,key,{value: value})
            const verified = await multisig
                .connect(acc5)
                .verify(from, to, value, key, _signature)
                console.log(verified)     // it is returning the whole signature
                console.log(acc5.address)
            assert.equal(verified, from, "error")
        })
```

I want to get the verified address.

**Extra info:** `submit()` is looks like this:

```
function submit(address _to, bytes32 _key) public payable {
        
        require(msg.value > 0);
        uint256 _value = msg.value / 10 ** 18;
        submitted[msg.sender] = true;
        transaction[msg.sender] = Transaction(_to, _value, _key);
        emit SubmittedWithValue(msg.sender, "submitted", _value, "ether");
        emit TransactionSetFor(
            "Transaction is set for",
            _value,
            "by",
            msg.sender,
            "for",
            _to
        );
    }
```

Comment: The function `verify` is not a view or pure, so it creates a transaction and it is returning the transaction hash.